# REST calling is double executed at the time of multistep execution of Observable.subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

Application is using Angular 2.4.3.
The problem that a REST calling is double executed by once in 2-3 months at present occurs.
Please tell me solution method.

The **flow of processing** is as follows.

(1) a button is clicked.

(2) `REST1` is executed.

(3) when ResponseStatus of `REST1` was `200`, `REST2` is executed.

**above-mentioned (3) `REST2` is double executed**.

It's double executed by log of `RESTService` the same time.

The **sample code** is as follows.
I'm doing multistep execution of `Observable.subscribe`, but are there any problems in the code contents?

```
// (2) execution of REST1
let observable: Observable<Response> = this.http.get(requestOptions);
observable.subscribe((response: Response) => {
    let responseData: any = response.response.json();

    if (200 === response.status) {
        no1 = responseData.xxx.no1;
        no2 = responseData.xxx.no2;
        no3 = responseData.xxx.no2;

        // Abbreviation

        let requestOptions: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headerParameters,
            search: urlParameters
        });
        let body = {
            "no1": no1,
            "no2": no2,
            "no3": no3,
        };
        let xxxDaoData: XxxDaoData = new XxxDaoData();
        xxxDaoData.data = body;

        // (3) execution of REST2 (REST is double executed)
        let observable2: Observable<Response> = this.http.post(xxxDaoData, requestOptions);
        observable2.subscribe((response: Response) => {
            // Abbreviation
        }
    }
}
```

If there are bug information on Angular and a case, please tell me.

Comment: So **REST, REST1 and REST2** all are different

Comment: How about checking responseData for null before executing Rest 2?

Comment: @RukshanDangalla I checked the log, I think `REST2` is executed double at the same time. Therefore I think it can't be avoided in null check in responseData.

Answer (score 0):

[Live Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t1gmer?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

It must be to imperative approached you are using to chaining your request, please try the reactive way:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

let request = observable.pipe(
  concatMap(val => {
    ... somecode
    return observable2;
  })
);

request.subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this method.